# SafeAreaView implementation on iPhone 11

Tags: ios, react-native, safeareaview

I'm trying to add a SafeAreaView so my icons don't get squished together like shown in the image.

But it seems the SafeAreaView just pushes the contents up instead.

This is how I've currently Implemented it/

```
const BottomTabs = () => (
  <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
    <DevSupport />
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={FeaturedScreen}
        options={{
          unmountOnBlur: true,
          tabBarLabel: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Icons.IconHome width={ICON_SIZE} height={ICON_SIZE} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  </SafeAreaView>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Any tips on where I'm going wrong? Or am I simply adding the SafeAreaView on the wrong screen?

[image: Error Occurring here]

Without SafeArea it looks like the following:

[image: WithoutSafearea]

Answer (score 0):

BottomTab had SafeAreaView so you don't need to wrap it in SafeAreaView.

```
const BottomTabs = () => (
  <Tab.Navigator>
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={FeaturedScreen}
      options={{
        unmountOnBlur: true,
        tabBarLabel: 'Home',
        tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
          <Icons.IconHome width={ICON_SIZE} height={ICON_SIZE} color={color} />
        ),
      }}
    />
  </Tab.Navigator>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Comment: I added that safearea

Comment: You can add SafeAreaView into the screen if it doesn't have a header bar. If the screen wrap by the bottom tab you don't need care about the bottom padding

Comment: It doesn't wrap the whole screen

Comment: Only wraps the bottom of the screen